# Reading from a online data API using AJAX/JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ajax

Sorry if this is a foolish question, I'm just finding hard to wrap my head around how to do this without just running out and learning ten million frameworks...

I want to query an online database (specifically https://data.qld.gov.au/dataset/fireworks/resource/346d58fc-b7c1-4c38-bf4d-c9d5fb43ce7b).

The end goal is to be able to display this information on a website. My first idea was to just create a small website locally and take one of their ajax queries, but it won't connect.

What is the simplest way to query a data API?
(I'm working with HTML/CSS/JS, and have started learning Node.js, JSON data and AJAX, but I'm new).

I have right now a website that I'm just opening locally (i.e. it's address is file:///C:/Users/Dylan/fireworks/getinfo.html) and very simple HTML and javascript copied from the website. But the alert always returns undefined, telling me that it's not actually trying to connect. What am I missing here and why?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var data = {
    resource_id: '346d58fc-b7c1-4c38-bf4d-c9d5fb43ce7b', // the resource id
    limit: 5, // get 5 results
    q: 'jones' // query for 'jones'
  };

  console.log("got here");
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://data.qld.gov.au/api/action/datastore_search',
    data: data,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(data) {
      alert('Total results found: ' + data.result.total)
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <script src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src = "getinfo.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
 <h1> I hate myself </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

I know it sounds like too broad of a question, if your answers are broad that's okay. I just want to know what I need to learn in order to complete the simple task of retrieving information off of an online database, and why I can't just query it from my computer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were so close!!  You were just trying to get a count from the `result` variable but thats a hashtable/dictionary rather than an array.   Try getting the count by calling the `length` method on `result.records`

Note that I removed the `q` param so we actually get some records back

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var data = {
    resource_id: '346d58fc-b7c1-4c38-bf4d-c9d5fb43ce7b', // the resource id
    limit: 5, // get 5 results
    // q: 'jones' // query for 'jones' remove this so we actually get some records
  };

  console.log("got here");
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://data.qld.gov.au/api/action/datastore_search',
    data: data,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(successData) {
      alert('Total results found: ' + successData.result.records.length)
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <script src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src = "getinfo.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
 <h1> I am a golden god </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Every thing is fine in your code, But you are referencing a wrong variable, Just `console.log(data)` to see what properties or methods the data object contains.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var data = {
    resource_id: '346d58fc-b7c1-4c38-bf4d-c9d5fb43ce7b', // the resource id
    limit: 5, // get 5 results
    q: 'jones' // query for 'jones'
  };

  console.log("got here");
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://data.qld.gov.au/api/action/datastore_search',
    data: data,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);

      // alert('Total results found: ' + data.result.total)
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <script src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src = "getinfo.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
 <h1> I hate myself </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't load the url, it returned a http 408/409 error. So I can't tell you what's wrong but how to debug what's wrong.

Next time you found this, Step 1, open your browser's debugger; Step 2, check "Network" tab if there is a failure in connection and watch the error message; Step 3, `console.log(data)`, it will shows the data structure into the console, in many case, undefined comes from mistaken usage of data structure. Finally, don't hate youself and ask for help.